# Plotting a flat csv list throws None of [Float64Index ... are in the [columns]"

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot a very simple csv list. From reading similar questions I explicitly set the delimiter, although that shouldn't be necessary in this case. The error messages says the lat data are not in the columns, but they are? Aren't they? Sorry for that rookie problem.

sample.csv content:

```
lat,lon
41.3183890,2.1034560
41.3184440,2.1034180
41.3184960,2.1033760
41.3185610,2.1033510
41.3186100,2.1033080
41.3186690,2.1032710
41.3187210,2.1032330
41.3187800,2.1031950
41.3188360,2.1031580
41.3188970,2.1031240
```

My code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

df_list = pd.read_csv('sample.csv', delimiter=",", header=0)
df_list.plot(df_list['lat'], df_list['lon'])
```

The error:

> KeyError: "None of [Float64Index([41.380008000000004,          41.379993,          41.379975,\n                       41.379939,          41.379921,          41.379883,\n                       41.379852,          41.379815,          41.379778,\n                       41.379739,\n              ...\n                       41.380067, 41.380041999999996,          41.380016,\n
>     41.37999, 41.379965999999996,          41.379982,\n                       41.380025,          41.380067,          41.380108,\n                       41.380142],\n             dtype='float64', length=4709)] are in the [columns]"

Comment: Either `df_list.plot(x='lat', y='lon')` or `plt.plot(df_list['lat'], df_list['lon'])`.

Comment: Thanks, i mixed up the two different plot methods then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your last line of code with the following:

```
df_list.plot('lat', 'lon')
```